# Can I have a Viewpager on an Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am having 3 `Fragments Tabs` that are bound to a `Fragment` Activity using 
`viewpager`, Now I need one of these Fragment also have a ViewPager that again bound to some other three Fragments tabs, How can I achive it?
I had achieved the first structure, i.e. `FragmentActivity` having 3 fragments Tabs on it via a view pager. I need the second structure. i.e. one of these Fragment again have three fragments Tabs on it via a Viewpager.